# Не могу решить задачу по Python

Tags: python

Совсем недавно начал изучать python и не получается решить задачу из-за ошибки

```py
sn = input().split()
mark = input().split()
retry = []
done = []
for i in range(len(sn)):
    if mark[i] >= 4:
        done.append(sn[i])
    else:
        retry.apend(sn[i])
print(*retry)
print(*done)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6032/2658902450.py in <module>
      5 done = []
      6 for i in range(len(sn)):
----> 7     if mark[i] >= 4:
      8         done.append(sn[i])
      9     else:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

1 Скриншот - условие.
2 Скриншот - то, чем можно пользоваться и предлагаемый алгоритм решения.
[image: Условие]

[image: То, чем можно пользоваться и предлагаемый алгоритм решения]

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: а как отредактировать?

Comment: Нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1381063/edit) под самим вопросом

Comment: всё, переделал.

Comment: `mark` это список строк, а строки нельзя сравнивать с числами

Comment: я это понимаю, но не знаю как это исправить

Comment: Использовать `int()` где-нибудь

Comment: я пробовал поставить int, когда задавал список с числами int(input()).split(). Так не получилось. Так же, пробовал в цикле for задать то, что work[i] это число. Так тоже не получилось

Comment: `if int(mark[i]) >= 4:`

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение вашей задачи. Считываются имена, считываются и переводятся в числа отметки, создаются списки несдавших и сдавших, заполняются, распечатываются:

```
names = input().split()
marks = list(map(int, input().split()))

lists = {False: [], True: []}
for n, m in zip(names, marks):
    lists[m >= 4].append(n)

for lst in lists.values():
    print(*lst)
```

**P.S.** `len()` и `range()` не пригодились. `for` не соответствует требуемому. Требуется `for i in range(len(...)):` который в Питоне нужен очень редко. Чуствую, отчислят меня из ВШЭ. :)

**P.P.S.** Про ошибку не написал. В других ответах уже сказали что не надо разные типы сравнивать.

**P.P.P.S** Вы в Jupyter Notebook работаете. Это не лучшая среда. Она удобна для простых вещей, но прививает плохие привычки. Попробуйте PyCharm или VSCode или редактор и командную строку. Так у вас будет правильная удобная среда с подсказками и отладчиком. Чем сложнее код, тем важнее использовать правильное окружение.

Answer (score 1):

У вас надо было ввод в числа преобразовывать: Для списков это делается через `list(map(int, input().split()))`. `map` применяет функцию `int` к каждому элементу списка

```
sn = input().split()
mark = list(map(int, input().split()))
retry = []
done = []
for i in range(len(sn)):
    if mark[i] >= 4:
        done.append(sn[i])
    else:
        retry.append(sn[i])
print(*retry)
print(*done)
```

Или можно немножко по другому:

```
sn = input().split()
mark = input().split()
retry = []
done = []
for i in range(len(sn)):
    if int(mark[i]) >= 4:
        done.append(sn[i])
    else:
        retry.append(sn[i])
print(*retry)
print(*done)
```

***P.S.**  С числами нельзя работать без `int`!!!*

Comment: я исправил @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: `apend` -> `append`.